# How to write a regex expression for custom syntax highlighting

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I want to write a regex expression that will match the following text:

```
200502-title-of-something
```

I would like the expression to match any occurrence of a six digit date followed by a string of text separated by dashes.

I am using this for custom syntax highlighting in a sublime-syntax file (YAML 1.2).

Comment: This is really close except it is also matching any number that comes after a dash. Is there a way to limit it to only the numbers that appear in the string beginning with the six-digit date?

Comment: You should edit your question to include what you tried so far.

Comment: Does the date have defined format? That is, is it necessary that only a date should match and not a string like ```998877```?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like the expression to match any occurrence of a six digit date `\d{6}`
followed by a string of text `[a-zA-Z]+`
separated by dashes`-`.

To summarize:

```
\b\d{6}(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)+\b
```

where:

- `\b` is a word boundary
- `-` a hyphen
- `[a-zA-Z]+` a character class that matches 1 or more letters
- `(?:...)+` a non capture group, that may appear 1 or more times

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/D0QcvB/1)

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.